# Magento2 Blank category list page after migration

Tags: magento2, category-products, magento2-migration-tool, media-images, category-listing

We successfully migrated a huge multi-store site from `magento-1.9.3` to `magento-2.1.6` last week using Magento migration tool. After migration, we notice that categories are not listing any products although products are there all set in admin. Also we reindexed everything but the issue still remain there until we put the media folder from `magento1.9.3` to migrated `magento2.1.3/pub/` directory.

We've checked this issue and it seems that `Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View::getProductListHtml()` function returns empty product listing html when there is not media with product images.

The case is not same with other magento stores as having a blank media only replaces the placeholders images. My question is, why it is necessary for me to place the old media folder will all images in order to render the products list successfully under categories?

*PS: permissions are set properly for pub, no custom module is overriding any class, all the commands (static content, reindex, cacha clean, di compilation) ran completely.*

Comment: Please check your Magento2 default placeholder image. I think it is not present at that path so the product is not displayed. Please check it and then ping me. **@Salid**

Comment: And also check your debug.log file. Any error occurred or not.

Comment: @DhadukMitesh yes the issue was that there were some custom placeholder images from backend. After removing those placeholders from admin OR putting the placeholder images in media directory worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @DhadukMitesh, the issue was that there were some custom placeholder images set from backend.

```
Stores > Setting > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Product Image Placeholders
```

After removing those placeholders from admin OR putting the placeholder images in media directory worked for me.